# Blur Filter In CSS Keyframe Animation Makes Animation Choppy(non smooth). How Can I achieve Smooth animation with blurr filter?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

I just started using Css animation. I ran in to this problem. When I use blur filter the animation becomes really choppy but as I refresh the window it becomes slightly smoother and when I keep refreshing
it becomes more smoother. when I restart my Browser, It again shows choppy animation. Please Help Me solve this problem.

```
@keyframes slide-blur-translation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-1000px) scaleY(2.5) scaleX(0.2);
            transform: translateY(-1000px) scaleY(2.5) scaleX(0.2);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
            transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    -webkit-filter: blur(40px);
            filter: blur(40px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0) scaleY(1) scaleX(1);
            transform: translateY(0) scaleY(1) scaleX(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
            transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-filter: blur(0);
            filter: blur(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

CODE:

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
sleep(3000).then(() => {
  document.getElementsByClassName('element')[0].setAttribute('id', 'visible')
  for (i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName(`text${i}`)[0].setAttribute('style', `animation-delay:${0.07+(0.14*(i-1))}s;`)
    document.getElementsByClassName(`text${i}`)[0].setAttribute('id', 'animation')

  }
})
```

```css
#hidden {
  display: none;
}

#visible {
  position: absolute;
}

.text {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
}

.Sn {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}

.teamname {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

.win {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

.lose {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

.draw {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

.total {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

#animation {
  animation: slide-blur-translation 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000) both;
}

@keyframes slide-blur-translation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-1000px) scaleY(2.5) scaleX(0.2);
    transform: translateY(-1000px) scaleY(2.5) scaleX(0.2);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    -webkit-filter: blur(40px);
    filter: blur(40px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0) scaleY(1) scaleX(1);
    transform: translateY(0) scaleY(1) scaleX(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-filter: blur(0);
    filter: blur(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="element" id='hidden'>
  <div class='text1 row2'>

    <div class='Sn Sn8'>Hello</div>

    <div class='draw draw8'>123</div>
    <div class='total total8'>Friends</div>

  </div>
  <div class='text2 row2'>

    <div class='Sn Sn8'>HELLO</div>

    <div class='draw draw8'>123</div>
    <div class='total total8'>Friends</div>

  </div>
  <div class='text3 row2'>

    <div class='Sn Sn8'>HELLO</div>

    <div class='draw draw8'>123</div>
    <div class='total total8'>Friends</div>

  </div>
  <div class='text4 row2'>

    <div class='Sn Sn8'>HELLO</div>

    <div class='draw draw8'>123</div>
    <div class='total total8'>Friends</div>

  </div>
  <div class='text5 row2'>

    <div class='Sn Sn8'>HELLO</div>

    <div class='draw draw8'>123</div>
    <div class='total total8'>Friends</div>

  </div>
  <div class='text6 row2'>

    <div class='Sn Sn8'>HELLO</div>

    <div class='draw draw8'>123</div>
    <div class='total total8'>Friends</div>

  </div>
  <div class='text7 row2'>

    <div class='Sn Sn8'>HELLO</div>

    <div class='draw draw8'>123</div>
    <div class='total total8'>Friends</div>

  </div>
  <div class='text8 row2'>

    <div class='Sn Sn8'>HELLO</div>

    <div class='draw draw8'>123</div>
    <div class='total total8'>Friends</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show us what you are animating - in particular is it one image/several.... Perhaps put up a working snippet so we can see the problem for ourselves - and which browser/system are you using?

Comment: I am not seeing any choppiness - animating one image on Chrome/Firefox/Edge on Windows10 laptop and on Safari on iPad IOS 14.2.

Comment: I am animating Multiple divs with multiple Texts with animation delay through java script Using Windows10 Chrome/Edge Browser.

Comment: Could you put up a snippet that shows the problem, i.e. including any relevant HTML/JS,  as I cant reproduce it using just the CSS you have given.

Comment: @AHaworth I have added a sample code Have a look. Animation is laggy at first after refreshing it becomes smoother...

Comment: You're asking the compositor to do a lot of work, (blur filter is usually slow, having many transformed elements on top of each others + opacity means having several passes to render them etc. I'm not too surprised it lags a bit, though quite interestingly in FF it's perfectly smooth.

Comment: I am not seeing any lag - apart of course from the JS-induced sleep at the start. I've tried on Edge, Chrome, Firefox on Windows10 and Safari on IOS 14.2 but as @Kaiido says I wouldn't be surprised if there were some lag especially on less powerful machines.

Comment: Not even seeing a problem with IE11.

Comment: Why It becomes smooth after refresh??? If I do Multiple Transitions Its choppy In First transition  only.

Comment: Was It lag Due to sleep I used???  When I removed sleep It ran smooth. is there any other way to execute sleep function??